# What happens if you don't lock before changing application variables?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

So yeah you're supposed to do this:

```
var application = HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance;
application.Lock();
application["SomeVariable"] = someValue;
application.Unlock();
```

But a lot of the time I've seen legacy code which just does this:

```
HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance["SomeVariable"] = someValue;
```

without using `Lock()`.

According to the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525184(v=vs.90).aspx),

> A page does not need to lock the application object to edit the application collection. If one page tries to edit the application collection without locking and a second page also tries to edit the collection, no error is sent by IIS and the Application object ends up in an inconsistent state.

What does this mean?

How are these legacy apps not blowing up when they fail to lock?

Comment: Isn't that help for ASP (non-NET)?

Comment: Ah wait... `HttpContext.Current.Application`! You wrote the "wrong" Application

Comment: [`ApplicationInstance` doesn't have a `Lock` method.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpapplication(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: `Application` has [`Lock`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpapplicationstate.lock(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Note that the `HttpApplicationState` is a strong limitation on the web site: it is only shared in the same machine (*within the scope of a virtual directory and its subdirectories on a single web server*)... You can't host your web site on multiple machines to speedup it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are referencing ancient documentation for ASP.

The [ASP.NET documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpapplicationstate.lock(v=vs.110).aspx) reads:

> The HttpApplicationState class performs automatic locking and unlocking with the AllKeys and Count properties and the Add, Clear, Get, GetKey, Remove, RemoveAt and Set methods. However, explicitly using the Lock and UnLock methods when you have a series of operations may be more efficient.

So this is solely a performance optimization thing, nothing more. You can't end up with an invalid state since `Set` locks itself.

Comment: I'll add here the link to the [reference source](https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System.Web/httpapplicationstate.cs) so the OP can check for himself if he needs :-)

Comment: And the documentation is "logically" wrong *However, explicitly using the Lock and UnLock methods when you have a series of operations **may be more efficient.***: You need to put manually a lock if you want to do multiple operations and you want to be Atomic/Consistent. There is no "efficient" option here.

Answer (score -1):

If you do not lock, you risk getting a [race condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition).

And even a remote danger of race condition is too much. If you run your code long enough or parelell enough, you *will* run into a race condition. And that is a ASP page/Webserver, paralellism is what they are all about.
You need to be aware they can happen and how they happen, or they *will* happen and you will have a hell of a time finding out why the application behaves a certain way.

Comment: No, you can't. Read the ASP.NET documentation referenced in my answer.